# Downloading *.gz zipped file with python requests corrupt it

Tags: python, gzip, python-requests

I use this code (it is only a part) to download *.gz archive.

```
with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_to_site_URL, payload)    
    load = s.get(scene, stream=True)

    with open(path_to_file, "wb") as save_command:
        for chunk in load.iter_content(chunk_size=1024, decode_unicode=False):
            if chunk:
                save_command.write(chunk)
                save_command.flush()
```

After download the size of the file is twice more than when I download file by clicking "save as" on it. And the file is corrupted.
Link for the file is:[`http://www.zsrcpod.aviales.ru/modistlm/archive/tlm/geo/00000/28325/terra_77835_20140806_060059.geo.hdf.gz`](http://www.zsrcpod.aviales.ru/modistlm/archive/tlm/geo/00000/28325/terra_77835_20140806_060059.geo.hdf.gz)

File require login and password, so I add a screenshot of what I see when I follow the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGqtS.jpg

Looks like some options set to define this archive as a text.

file.header is:

```
{'content-length': '58277138',
'content-encoding': 'gzip',
'set-cookie': 'cidaviales=53616c7465645f5fc8f0abdb26f7b0536784ae4e8b302410a288f1f67ccc0afd13ce067d97ba237dc27749d9957f30457f1a1d9763b03637; path=/,
 avialestime=1407386483; path=/; expires=Wed,
 05-Nov-2014 04:41:23 GMT,
ciddaviales=53616c7465645f5fc8f0abdb26f7b0536784ae4e8b302410a288f1f67ccc0afd13ce067d97ba237dc27749d9957f30457f1a1d9763b03637; domain=aviales.ru; path=/',
'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
'server': 'Apache/1.3.37 (Unix) mod_perl/1.30',
'last-modified': 'Wed, 06 Aug 2014 06:17:14 GMT',
'etag': '"21d4e63-3793d12-53e1c86a"',
'date': 'Thu, 07 Aug 2014 04:41:23 GMT',
'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=windows-1251'}
```

How to properly download this file using python requests library?

Comment: It could be that it automatically decompresses the gzip content, have you checked what is inside downloaded data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like **requests** automatically decompresses the content for you. See [here](http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/requests/latest/requests.pdf)

> Requests automatically decompresses gzip-encoded responses, and does
>   its best to decode response content to unicode when possible. You can
>   get direct access to the raw response (and even the socket), if needed
>   as well

This is default behaviour if *Accept-Encoding* request header contains *gzip*. You can check this by printing **s.request.headers**. To be able to get raw data you should modify this  *headers* dict to exclude *gzip*, however in your case the decompressed data looks like valid *hdf* file - so, just save it with this extension and use it!

Comment: Looks like u are damn right. The size of downloaded file is the same as unpacked file downloaded manually. Does this mean I download more traffic? Or requests download archive for me and then unpack archive?

Comment: @user2829863 no, you don't download more, you download archived data, but then requests module unpacks it for you.