# facebook-analytics export api download gzip

Tags: python, export, python-requests, facebook-analytics

I am new to using the Facebook-analytics export api, and was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot my current issue.  I am trying to follow the following link to download the event data that is being generated through the Facebook-analytics sdk on my mobile app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export#download-file

I have been able to correctly execute steps one and two using the python requests library, but I am having trouble with step three.  For some reason when I make the http call using requests to download the file, the content that is return from the GET call is a bunch of html code that does not look like the example event data in the link above.  Here is the requests calls I am making:

## creates request

```
access_token = '######ACCESS_TOKEN######'
start_ts = '1495322078'
end_ts = '1495408478'

def get_fb_token(app_id, app_secret):           
    payload = {'access_token': access_token, 'start_ts': start_ts, 'end_ts': end_ts}
    file = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/#####FBAPP_ID#######/analytics_app_events_exports', params = payload)
```

## query all exports

```
payload = {'access_token': access_token}
file = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/#####FBAPP_ID#######/analytics_app_events_exports?access_token', params = payload)
```

## download export file

```
id = '###EXPORT_ID#####'
filename = 'output.gz'
access_token = '####ACCESS_TOKEN#######'
payload = {'access_token': access_token, 'id': id, 'filename': filename}
file = requests.get('https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/analytics/app_events_export/download', params = payload)
```

Am I missing something?  The data from step three should be in file.content correct?  Where is output.gz being saved to?

## here are the headers that are associated to file.headers:

> {'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
>   'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Expires':
>   'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'public-key-pins-report-only':
>   'max-age=500;
>   pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=";
>   pin-sha256="r/mIkG3eEpVdm+u/ko/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E=";
>   pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ=";
>   report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/"', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
>   'X-FB-Debug':
>   '6ILkaUGMgE6MsB3PXIrxWT+c2PhWNrMGocvhbBcIYzakj4LoI1U+K+A5AFt7EpTe7PtrtbQ3gneI8PS0HIOFDw==',
>   'Date': 'Wed, 24 May 2017 01:22:17 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
>   'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store,
>   must-revalidate', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000;
>   preload', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type':
>   'text/html', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'}

## here is a sample of the html content that is returned from file.content:

> '\n\nwindow._cstart=+new
>   Date();function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d
>   in
>   a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy([\'Env\'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXgRLglhFB9mLdIE","timeslice_heartbeat_config":{"pollIntervalMs":33,"idleGapThresholdMs":60,"ignoredTimesliceNames":{"requestAnimationFrame":true,"Event
>   listenHandler mousemove":true,"Event listenHandler
>   mouseover":true,"Event listenHandler mouseout":true,"Event
>   listenHandler
>   scroll":true},"enableOnRequire":false},"shouldLogCounters":true,"timeslice_categories":{"react_render":true,"reflow":true},"dom_mutation_flag":true});**DEV**=0;CavalryLogger=window.CavalryLogger||function(a){this.lid=a;this.transition=false;this.metric_collected=false;this.is_detailed_profiler=false;this.instrumentation_started=false;this.pagelet_metrics={};this.events={};this.ongoing_watch={};this.values={t_cstart:window._cstart};this.piggy_values={};this.bootloader_metrics={};this.resource_to_pagelet_mapping={};this.e2eLogged=false;if(this.initializeInstrumentation)this.initializeInstrumentation();};CavalryLogger.prototype.setIsDetailedProfiler=function(a){this.is_detailed_profiler=a;return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.prototype.setTTIEvent=function(a){this.tti_event=a;return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.prototype.setValue=function(a,b,c,d){var
>   e=d?this.piggy_values:this.values;if(typeof
>   e[a]==\'undefined\'||c)e[a]=b;return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.prototype.getLastTtiValue=function(){return
>   this.lastTtiValue;};CavalryLogger.prototype.setTimeStamp=CavalryLogger.prototype.setTimeStamp||function(a,b,c,d){this.mark(a);var
>   e=this.values.t_cstart||this.values.t_start,f=d?e+d:CavalryLogger.now();this.setValue(a,f,b,c);if(this.tti_event&&a==this.tti_event){this.lastTtiValue=f;this.setTimeStamp(\'t_tti\',b);}return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.prototype.mark=typeof
>   console===\'object\'&&console.timeStamp?function(a){console.timeStamp(a);}:function(){};CavalryLogger.prototype.addPiggyback=function(a,b){this.piggy_values[a]=b;return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.instances={};CavalryLogger.id=0;CavalryLogger.perfNubMarkup="";CavalryLogger.getInstance=function(a){if(typeof
>   a==\'undefined\')a=CavalryLogger.id;if(!CavalryLogger.instances[a])CavalryLogger.instances[a]=new
>   CavalryLogger(a);return
>   CavalryLogger.instances[a];};CavalryLogger.setPageID=function(a){if(CavalryLogger.id===0){var
>   b=CavalryLogger.getInstance();CavalryLogger.instances[a]=b;CavalryLogger.instances[a].lid=a;delete
>   CavalryLogger.instances[0];}CavalryLogger.id=a;};CavalryLogger.setPerfNubMarkup=function(a){CavalryLogger.perfNubMarkup=a;};CavalryLogger.now=function(){if(window.performance&&performance.timing&&performance.timing.navigationStart&&performance.now)return
>   performance.now()+performance.timing.navigationStart;return new
>   Date().getTime();};CavalryLogger.prototype.measureResources=function(){};CavalryLogger.prototype.profileEarlyResources=function(){};CavalryLogger.getBootloaderMetricsFromAllLoggers=function(){};CavalryLogger.start_js=function(){};CavalryLogger.done_js=function(){};CavalryLogger.getInstance().setTTIEvent("t_domcontent");CavalryLogger.prototype.measureResources=function(a,b){if(!this.log_resources)return;var
>   c=\'bootload/\'+a.name;if(this.bootloader_metrics[c]!==undefined||this.ongoing_watch[c]!==undefined)return;var
>   d=CavalryLogger.now();this.ongoing_watch[c]=d;if(!(\'start_\'+c in
>   this.bootloader_metrics))this.bootloader_metrics[\'start_\'+c]=d;if(b&&!(\'tag_\'+c
>   in
>   this.bootloader_metrics))this.bootloader_metrics[\'tag_\'+c]=b;if(a.type===\'js\'){var
>   e=\'js_exec/\'+a.name;this.ongoing_watch[e]=d;}};CavalryLogger.prototype.stopWatch=function(a){if(this.ongoing_watch[a]){var
>   b=CavalryLogger.now(),c=b-this.ongoing_watch[a];this.bootloader_metrics[a]=c;var
>   d=this.piggy_values;if(a.indexOf(\'bootload\')===0){if(!d.t_resource_download)d.t_resource_download=0;if(!d.resources_downloaded)d.resources_downloaded=0;d.t_resource_download+=c;d.resources_downloaded+=1;if(d[\'tag_\'+a]==\'*EF*\')d.t_pagelet_cssload_early_resources=b;}delete
>   this.ongoing_watch[a];}return
>   this;};CavalryLogger.getBootloaderMetricsFromAllLoggers=function(){var
>   a={};Object.values(window.CavalryLogger.instances).forEach(function(b){if(b.bootloader_metrics)Object.assign(a,b.bootloader_metrics);});return
>   a;};CavalryLogger.start_js=function(a){for(var
>   b=0;bEF\');};CavalryLogger.getInstance().log_resources=true;CavalryLogger.getInstance().setIsDetailedProfiler(true);window.CavalryLogger&&CavalryLogger.getInstance().setTimeStamp("t_start");Facebook\n\n\n\nrequire("TimeSlice").guard(function()
>   {(require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["FluxConfig",[],{"ads_improve_perf_flux_container_subscriptions":false},2434],["PresenceInitialData",[],{"cookiePollInterval":500,"cookieVersion":3,"serverTime":"1495581411000","shouldSuppress":false,"useWebStorage":false},57],["RTCConfig",[],{},760],["MarketplaceSEOUtils",[],{"canonicalBaseURL":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com"},2231],["DateFormatConfig",[],{"numericDateOrder":["m","d","y"],"numericDateSeparator":"\/","shortDayNames":["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],"timeSeparator":":","weekStart":6,"formats":{"D":"D","D
>   g:ia":"D g:ia","D M d":"D M d","D M d, Y":"D M d, Y","D M j":"D M
>   j","D M j, g:ia":"D M j, g:ia","D M j, y":"D M j, y","D M j, Y
>   g:ia":"D M j, Y g:ia","D, M j, Y":"D, M j, Y","F d":"F d","F d, Y":"F
>   d, Y","F g":"F g","F j":"F j","F j, Y":"F j, Y","F j, Y \u0040 g:i
>   A":"F j, Y \u0040 g:i A","F j, Y g:i a":"F j, Y g:i a","F jS":"F
>   jS","F jS, g:ia":"F jS, g:ia","F jS, Y":"F jS, Y","F Y":"F Y","g A":"g
>   A","g:i":"g:i","g:i A":"g:i A","g:i a":"g:i
>   a","g:iA":"g:iA","g:ia":"g:ia","g:ia F jS, Y":"g:ia F jS, Y","g:iA l,
>   F jS":"g:iA l, F jS","g:ia M j":"g:ia M j","g:ia M jS":"g:ia M
>   jS","g:ia, F jS":"g:ia, F jS","g:iA, l M jS":"g:iA, l M
>   jS","g:sa":"g:sa","H:I - M d, Y":"H:I - M d, Y","h:i a":"h:i a","h:m:s
>   m\/d\/Y":"h:m:s m\/d\/Y","j":"j","l F d, Y":"l F d, Y","l g:ia":"l
>   g:ia","l, F d, Y":"l, F d, Y","l, F j":"l, F j","l, F j, Y":"l, F j,
>   Y","l, F jS":"l, F jS","l, F jS, g:ia":"l, F jS, g:ia","l, M j":"l, M
>   j","l, M j, Y":"l, M j, Y","l, M j, Y g:ia":"l, M j, Y g:ia","M d":"M
>   d","M d, Y":"M d, Y","M d, Y g:ia":"M d, Y g:ia","M d, Y ga":"M d, Y
>   ga","M j":"M j","M j, Y":"M j, Y","M j, Y g:i A":"M j, Y g:i A","M j,
>   Y g:ia":"M j, Y g:ia","M jS, g:ia":"M jS, g:ia","M Y":"M Y","M y":"M
>   y","m-d-y":"m-d-y","M. d":"M. d","M. d, Y":"M. d, Y","j F Y":"j F
>   Y","m.d.y":"m.d.y","m\/d":"m\/d","m\/d\/Y":"m\/d\/Y","m\/d\/y":"m\/d\/y","m\/d\/Y
>   g:ia":"m\/d\/Y g:ia","m\/d\/y H:i:s":"m\/d\/y H:i:s","m\/d\/Y
>   h:m":"m\/d\/Y h:m","n":"n","n\/j":"n\/j","n\/j, g:ia":"n\/j,
>   g:ia","n\/j\/y":"n\/j\/y","Y":"Y","Y-m-d":"Y-m-d","Y\/m\/d":"Y\/m\/d","y\/m\/d":"y\/m\/d","j
>   \/ F \/ Y":"j \/ F \/
>   Y"},"ordinalSuffixes":{"1":"st","2":"nd","3":"rd","4":"th","5":"th","6":"th","7":"th","8":"th","9":"th","10":"th","11":"th","12":"th","13":"th","14":"th","15":"th","16":"th","17":"th","18":"th","19":"th","20":"th","21":"st","22":"nd","23":"rd","24":"th","25":"th","26":"th","27":"th","28":"th","29":"th","30":"th","31":"st"}},165],["ViewerContextDateData",[],{"gks":{"date_time_force_legacy_api":false}},1411],["RTISubscriptionManagerConfig",[],{"config":{"max_subscriptions":150,"www_idle_unsubscribe_min_time_ms":600000,"www_idle_unsubscribe_times_ms":{"feedback_like_subscribe":600000,"comment_like_subscribe":600000,"feedback_typing_subscribe":600000,"comment_create_subscribe":1800000},"autobot_tiers":{"latest":"realtime.skywalker.autobot.latest","intern":"realtime.skywalker.autobot.intern","sb":"realtime.skywalker.autobot.sb"}},"autobot":{},"assimilator":{},"unsubscribe_release":true},1081],["LocaleInitialData",[],{"locale":"en_US","language":"English
>   (US)"},273],["MessengerURIConstants",[],{"ARCHIVED_PATH":"\/archived","COMPOSE_SUBPATH":"\/new","GROUPS_PATH":"\/groups","PEOPLE_PATH":"\/people","SUPPORT_PATH":"\/support","FILTERED_REQUESTS_PATH":"\/filtered","MESSAGE_REQUESTS_PATH":"\/requests","THREAD_PREFIX":"\/t\/","GROUP_PREFIX":"group-","FACEBOOK_PREFIX":"\/messages"},1912],["PresencePrivacyInitialData",[],{},58],["MercuryParticipantsConstants",[],{"UNKNOWN_GENDER":0,"EMAIL_IMAGE":"\/images\/messaging\/threadlist\/envelope.png","IMAGE_SIZE":32,"BIG_IMAGE_SIZE":50},109],["MessagingConfig",[],{"SEND_CONNECTION_RETRIES":2,"syncFetchRetries":2,"syncFetchInitialTimeoutMs":1500,"syncFetchTimeoutMultiplier":1.2,"syncFetchRequestTimeoutMs":10000},97],["MercuryServerRequestsConfig",[],{"sendMessageTimeout":45000},107],["FantailConfig",["FantailLogQueue"],{"FantailLogQueue":{"__m":"FantailLogQueue"}},1258],["PECurrencyConfig",[],{"currency_map_for_render":{"AED":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0625.","offset":100,"screen_name":"UAE
>   Dirham"},"AMD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u0564\u0580.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"ANG":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"ANG","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"AOA":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"AOA","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"ARS":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Argentine
>   Peso"},"AUD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Australian
>   Dollar"},"AWG":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"AWG","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"BAM":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"BAM","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"BBD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"Bds$","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"BDT":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u09f3","offset":100,"screen_name":"Bangladeshi
>   Taka"},"BGN":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u043b\u0432.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Bulgarian
>   Lev"},"BHD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0628.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Bahraini
>   Dinar"},"BOB":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"Bs.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Bolivian
>   Boliviano"},"BRL":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"R$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Brazilian
>   Real"},"BYN":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"Br","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"CAD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Canadian
>   Dollar"},"CHF":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"Fr.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Swiss
>   Franc"},"CLP":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"$","offset":1,"screen_name":"Chilean
>   Peso"},"CNY":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\uffe5","offset":100,"screen_name":"Chinese
>   Yuan"},"COP":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"$","offset":1,"screen_name":"Colombian
>   Peso"},"CRC":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u20a1","offset":1,"screen_name":"Costa
>   Rican Colon"},"CZK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"K\u010d","offset":100,"screen_name":"Czech
>   Koruna"},"DKK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"kr.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Danish
>   Krone"},"DZD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"DA","offset":100,"screen_name":"Algerian
>   Dinar"},"EGP":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062c.\u0645.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Egyptian
>   Pound"},"EUR":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"\u20ac","offset":100,"screen_name":"Euro"},"FBZ":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"C","offset":100,"screen_name":"credits"},"GBP":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u00a3","offset":100,"screen_name":"British
>   Pound"},"GHS":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"GHS","offset":100,"screen_name":"Ghanaian
>   Cedi"},"GTQ":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"Q","offset":100,"screen_name":"Guatemalan
>   Quetzal"},"HKD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Hong
>   Kong Dollar"},"HNL":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"L.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Honduran
>   Lempira"},"HRK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"kn","offset":100,"screen_name":"Croatian
>   Kuna"},"HUF":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"Ft","offset":1,"screen_name":"Hungarian
>   Forint"},"IDR":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"Rp","offset":1,"screen_name":"Indonesian
>   Rupiah"},"ILS":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"\u20aa","offset":100,"screen_name":"Israeli New
>   Shekel"},"INR":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"\u20b9","offset":100,"screen_name":"Indian
>   Rupee"},"ISK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"kr.","offset":1,"screen_name":"Iceland
>   Krona"},"JOD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0627.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Jordanian
>   Dinar"},"JPY":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u00a5","offset":1,"screen_name":"Japanese
>   Yen"},"KES":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"KSh","offset":100,"screen_name":"Kenyan
>   Shilling"},"KRW":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u20a9","offset":1,"screen_name":"Korean
>   Won"},"KWD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0643.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"KYD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"CI$","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"LKR":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"LKR","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"LTL":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"Lt","offset":100,"screen_name":"Lithuanian
>   Litas"},"LVL":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"Ls","offset":100,"screen_name":"Latvian
>   Lats"},"MAD":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0645.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"MOP":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"MOP","offset":100,"screen_name":"Macau
>   Patacas"},"MUR":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"MUR","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"MVR":{"format":"","symbol":"\u0783.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"MXN":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Mexican
>   Peso"},"MYR":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"RM","offset":100,"screen_name":"Malaysian
>   Ringgit"},"MZN":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"MT","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"NGN":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u20a6","offset":100,"screen_name":"Nigerian
>   Naira"},"NIO":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"C$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Nicaraguan
>   Cordoba"},"NOK":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"kr","offset":100,"screen_name":"Norwegian
>   Krone"},"NZD":{"format":"{amount}{symbol}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"New
>   Zealand Dollar"},"OMR":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u0631.\u0639.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"PAB":{"format":"{symbol} {amount}","symbol":"B\/.","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"PEN":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"S\/.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Peruvian Nuevo
>   Sol"},"PHP":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u20b1","offset":100,"screen_name":"Philippine
>   Peso"},"PKR":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"Rs","offset":100,"screen_name":"Pakistani
>   Rupee"},"PLN":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"z\u0142","offset":100,"screen_name":"Polish
>   Zloty"},"PYG":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"\u20b2","offset":1,"screen_name":"Paraguayan
>   Guarani"},"QAR":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u0631.\u0642.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Qatari
>   Rials"},"RON":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"lei","offset":100,"screen_name":"Romanian
>   Leu"},"RSD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"RSD","offset":100,"screen_name":"Serbian
>   Dinar"},"RUB":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"p.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Russian
>   Ruble"},"SAR":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u0631.\u0633.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Saudi
>   Arabian Riyal"},"SEK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"kr","offset":100,"screen_name":"Swedish
>   Krona"},"SGD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Singapore
>   Dollar"},"SKK":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"Sk","offset":100,"screen_name":"Slovak
>   Koruna"},"SRD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"SRD","offset":100,"screen_name":null},"THB":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"\u0e3f","offset":100,"screen_name":"Thai
>   Baht"},"TRY":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"TL","offset":100,"screen_name":"Turkish
>   Lira"},"TWD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"NT$","offset":1,"screen_name":"Taiwan
>   Dollar"},"TZS":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"TSh","offset":1,"screen_name":"Tanzanian
>   Shilling"},"UAH":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u0433\u0440\u043d.","offset":100,"screen_name":"Ukrainian
>   Hryvnia"},"USD":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"US
>   Dollars"},"UYU":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"$U","offset":100,"screen_name":"Uruguay
>   Peso"},"VEF":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"Bs","offset":100,"screen_name":"Venezuelan
>   Bolivar"},"VND":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u20ab","offset":1,"screen_name":"Vietnamese
>   Dong"},"XAF":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"FCFA","offset":1,"screen_name":null},"XOF":{"format":"{symbol}{amount}","symbol":"FCFA","offset":1,"screen_name":null},"ZAR":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"R","offset":100,"screen_name":"South African
>   Rand"}},"currency_map_for_cc":{"AED":{"format":"{amount}
>   {symbol}","symbol":"\u062f.\u0625.","offset":100,"screen_name":"UAE
>   Dirham"},"ARS":{"format":"{symbol}
>   {amount}","symbol":"$","offset":100,"screen_name":"Argentine

## file.content with headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}:

> '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe5\x99Yo\xe2X\x10\x85\xdf\xe7W\xb4x\xf6\xa5\xefRw\xa9\xc7{\xbd\xbcLw:\x1a\x927$d\xc0\xccXML\x86e&\xf9\xf7S\x06BB:\xa41\xc9\xc4H\x1d!\xb1\x842\xf0q\xea\xd4)#\x005p\xad\x84\x8e&\xc3\xc1\xcdlXN\x8b\xc1\xb8\xc8G\xcb\xf2\x9f|Y\x0c\xf2\xdb\xdb\xa8\x9c-\x06\xab\xea{5\xfb\xb7\x8ad\x97\xf3\xc8p\xc3\xe9JP\xadBc\xb8\x8d:\xb2\x13u\xae\xab\xd14_,\xcaIY\x8c\xe9\xee\xa2\xa0\xdb\xb3j\xf0\xf7*\xaf\x96\xf9\x00:Q\xff\xe2\x1d.\xcb\xf9\xaa\xa8\xaf;Y(\xbf\xf5z\xc9\xef]\xe8\n\xdb\xe5\x9f\xaf\xabry\xdf\xb5]\xec\xd2Ku\xca\xcb|\x0c\xfd\xc8\xd67\xbf\xf5>\t\xdeU]\xd1\x89\xfcM1/G\xf9\xe7\xaf\xb3j9/\xf2it1\x8b\xf3\xf9\xbc,\xe6\x91\xe0\x12\xee\xacqw\xeb\xcfH@dT\xcd\x06\xab2\x9a\xe4\xd3E\x119\xa7\x94I0f\xca\x9a\x94A\xc0\x84yI\xb7\x9cKP\xa56\x86\xd8\xcb\xdf\xc4K8_\x87I\x1f\xe5\xa1js\xef\x1d/g\xcfJI\xa7%6eUW\th\x8f\x95\xecG\xb0e\x85\x84J\x1f\x87J\xacQ\xa9H\xed\xa1\xf2\xb13&s\x9c\x01\x82g\xa0\xe2\xc0\xbcN\x02\xb3)\x80\xe5\x021\xcbp#+\xa3QA\x83.\x05-\xe4\xaeM\x1d\n\x83Q\x87\xff\xb4MM+m\n\x07\xa4\xf7G\xf1gY\xe5\x07\x85\xa7\xe8\xd3\xed+/\xf6\x99P\x1c,\xe3\xce\x03\x03\x9d\x19\xe6c\xed\x19:\x91\x1a\xb4>Ck\xb7\xcaC\xc9\xb1\x01N|\x84)\x1d9\xe010\xc5\xc7\xc3lE\x9b?\xc0<\xb2\x8dQ\xa0\xfa\xc5\xdaX)\x81\xfa
>   *z\xec)*\xb9C\xb5\xa9j\r\x95\xeeG\xeaY\x8b^\xf7>_\xe6#\x12\xfe\xe8`{\x1a2!\xdcbZ\xbf\x98Vq\x8c:\xb5LrC\x94R\xb4\xd4\x98R\x12\xa5L\xd0|\x08:\xc1t+(\xcb\xe1\xa9\xd9M\xca\xf9bY#\x1aL\xf3U5\xfa\xeb\x15Q\xad+;\xabjq[\x8c\xb6}\xf9\x01\xd0^\x04%\x1b\x8dQij7\xa3co%\xe5\x83M\x83I\x98\x01@\x06\x9e$\xe5T\x12\xb3\x10\x82C\xee\x1dW><H\n\xb4:\tV])[\x83E\xc6/N\xcd\x1c\xa4-a\x1ea\xa9$h\x9d:\xc3\xb4\xd6\x86\x94\xe5\x1cs\x9c\x12\x07\xa9\xc1\x1b\xfa\xf3q\xba\xeb?0\xa2\xb1UQ\x15\x98\xf6\xfa\xef\xed\xa4\x9e\x9aU\x03X\x1ci\xd25\xc8\x1c\xa0\x1f\xa7\xa4\x05g\x8f\x99\x92\xea\xe3\xa7\xe4\xdb\xdbt\xcf\xfc\x8f\xef\xd4g<\x8f\x14\x1fw\xa8\xdb\x13_[\xb0\x1c\xb7F5\x86EU\xe0\xda\x83u8T\\\xcd\xe6Dk\xf6Z\xa6\xd8\'eB\xa6Lf\x15eY\xe2Cq^\xb0\xc0\x85bh\xbc\x93@\x83\x14\x13\xff4S\xf8\xdb\xdb/\x1b\xbf\xff!F\x88]Wn\x9e\xda1\x13\xc3\xc7z\xa8\xd8\xa4@\xfa\x16\xd4\x90\x93\x05L$C\x80\xa1\x93C\xb2\xc8B\x7f\xc8(8\x8b\xb0!\xadj>\x12\xa8J\xb4;\x12\xe4\x81\x91\x90\x8eoj\xa5U\xd1U\xfa\xe5\xba\xf7|Y\x17X?\xb2\xa74\t\x18\x9b\x98\xd2kH\xea\x81\x00\x8e\xda\x91\'\x19\xd3F\xf1,K\x12E\xc3b\x97\xcb\xb4m\x8e\x8a2\x99\xfc\xf5\x0c\x0c\xad>!jPU\xcbQ\xe3\xc1\xc0\xdcSR\xaf\xd8\xd7FW\xf2\xd9JD\x86eM\x86\xd4z2\xd0^\x14\x0b\xea?+h%2!\xd5\x19\xad\xe3FoEE\x8e\x84\xcdEEU\xaeEQ\xb5u\xc2LZ)N[\x8c\xd6\x95-f\xfd7\xd9U\xff\xa2\xb1W)\xcbO\x90\x15U9\xd1\x9e\xac\x0e\xe7\x87\xc3\xe7\xc2\x1e\xe2\x83xn\xeaA\xd1\xd6\xc2B\xe6\xa9\t)B2\x97b\xca\x02`\x02\x16i\n\xa6\xb0\x8b\x0f`^\xd3\xd4k\xa7%\xa8\xf2<\x96\xedfAa\xa7\xa7\xe3c\x82\x92\xdc\xba\xe6z\xa2\xe3\xb6hS\xa4\'}r\x1e\xdd7t!\x84\x8eeL2\xf2I}\xa2\x8b\\=\x04+\x18"\x8d<\x81\xa9\xb7f\x93Gi\ttN\x1c^\x1b\xf3j<\x9f\x95\xe3\r\'\xb9\xdb\x18\x81\x83\xd0\xe2\x98\x8d\x91\xbf\xff\xc6\xe87\xef\xe9
>   \xcb\xdeWv%]\xfd\xd6\xb6\xcf\xfc\xa4\xbbb\xedb\x8b\xb2f\xf9\xfd~\xb6\xfe\xca\xe99w\x8esB\xa8T\xa4\xa9%\xd7\x87\xb9\x9c\xe6\xf7\xc5\xdc\xd7\x10\xe8\xde\xc3\x1a>VF[7f\xa8\x8b1\x83\x91\xa2\xf8\x9d\x8f4\x9b\x8c\x87F\x17|\x02
>   \xf5v\x13\x02\x0b\xcd\x9d\xcc\x01\x1d\xbe=\xe5\xb5rZ\x9f\xa4g\xf1\xe0\x8fo{\xc2\xeb_\xecT\'\xff\xc7\xed\xfa\x9c\x85\x05\xa2\x0ei\r\xce\xefH\xb4\x8f\x9b\xa4Ud\x87\xe7\xf9\x93R\x1bS\x94\xfeeOhR\xa4\xe0\xd2^\x93\xbe0B\x8f\x0e\xfc\x94\xccp\xff\xc4\xa2G\x9a\x10I\xa2Y&i?\x82`\x14\xc3D\x02\xb5\xa9W\x9a`A\x08|;K\x15\x99S\x13\xe1\xd5st\xa7<\xca\xb2\xa4<\xd1\xc6\x9c8\xd7]\xf39\xd0#\xc3\x89\x02\xdd\xe2\xae\xd9\x02\xac\xff\x00\xbb!gr\xf1"\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Answer (score 0):

Output.gz should be saved to the same directory where you are running your Python script. Is it not there? If you are getting HTML as a response you may need to set the content encoding header of the get request to accept gzip files (which should automatically decompress the file).

You need to iterate through the response to store it in output.gz. Here is a really good example: [Downloading *.gz zipped file with python requests corrupt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175884/downloading-gz-zipped-file-with-python-requests-corrupt-it)

Comment: The gzip file does not get saved in the working directory.  What would the accept header parameters look like?

Comment: Here's the documentation on the requests module that shows how to add a header. What is the HTML that is returned? Most of the time when I see HTML returned when I expected JSON or a file type it's because the HTML is some type of error page that will give me a clue as to what I did wrong in structuring the request. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: i added a sample of the html output.

Comment: I also added the headers from file.headers

Comment: Yeah the content type looks like it's set to text/HTML. Might need to be Content-Type: application/javascript

Comment: You might also consider checking what file.text returns.

Comment: changing the content-type to application/javascript or application/json did not seem to work.  and how would iterating through the request content change the data in the request?  I tried iterating the same way the thread to linked me to and saving to a .txt and .gz file and it just saved the same content in file.content :(

Comment: I was just suggesting that if you wanted to save the result to output.gz you would need to iterate through the response. It's definitely returning a JSON object at some point but there's a bunch of JavaScript the precedes the JSON objects. What does file.text return, anything more simple?

Comment: file.text returns the same thing