# What is the difference between download with browser and download with python-requests library?

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I have a file located at :
https://wzy-zone.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/remote_disk/Cambridge/sub51050.nii.gz

And when I download it from browser, it can be opened correctly, and can be recognized as a `.gz` file. 
[image]
However, when I download it with requests library and write it to local machine like that:

```
            full_address = os.path.join(prefix, category, name)
            print(full_address)
            response = requests.get(full_address)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                output_path = os.path.join('n4_bias', category, name)
                if not os.path.exists(output_path):
                    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(response.content)
```

It cannot be opened correctly, and the file type cannot be recognized correctly.
[image].

```
n4_bias/Atlanta/sub00368.nii.gz
agent = nib.load('n4_bias/Atlanta/sub00368.nii.gz')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImageFileError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2dfc10b95c7e> in <module>()
----> 1 agent = nib.load('n4_bias/Atlanta/sub00368.nii.gz')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nibabel/loadsave.py in load(filename, **kwargs)
     51 
     52     raise ImageFileError('Cannot work out file type of "%s"' %
---> 53                          filename)
     54 
     55 

ImageFileError: Cannot work out file type of "n4_bias/Atlanta/sub00368.nii.gz"
```

So, what is the difference between those two method?and how can I download a file using requests library?

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered here: [Downloading *.gz zipped file with python requests corrupt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175884/downloading-gz-zipped-file-with-python-requests-corrupt-it)

Seems `requests` is automatically de-compressing your archive already. Try removing the `.gz` file ending and opening the file as normal. If that works, change you python code to remove the `.gz` file extension. Something like:

```
with open(output_path[:-3], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works after I changed the code into:

```
full_address = os.path.join(prefix, category, name)
response = requests.get(full_address)
output_path = os.path.join('n4_bias', category, name)
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
   with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        f.flush()
```

The matter thing is the last code `f.flush()`,which will change the file point.